# How do you specify a negative step for an unsigned integer index in a VB.net for-loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, reverse, unsigned-integer

How do you specify a negative step on a unsigned integer index for a for-loop in VB.net

The following code will not compile:

```
Option Strict

For i as uLong = uLong.maxvalue To 0 Step -1UL
  ...
next i
```

Gives this:
**Error: BC30439    Constant expression not representable in type 'ULong'**

Comment: The syntax you followed is right and I didn't find any mistake and even I tried same code and it is working fine.

Comment: does not compile on OPTION STRICT

Comment: It is compiled successfully for me with option strict on

Comment: only if you have "Remove Integer Overflow Checks" on also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A unsigned Int16/Int32/Int64 cannot be represented as negative value, there is no way to do that, see **[ULong.MinValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**.

You have two options here:

- 1. Simulatte a negative step by using a while/until loop:

     ```
     Dim i As ULong = ULong.MaxValue

     While (i <> ULong.MinValue)
         Console.WriteLine(i)
         i -= 1UL ' Decrement current value by desired amount.
     End While
     ```
- 2. Set the **[/removeintchecks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/key2x70f%28VS.71%29.aspx)** vb's compiler parameter, then you can use negative values for unsigned datatypes.

     Note that you can set this parameter in a guided way trough the configuration page of the solution, in the "**Advanced Compile Options**", check "**Remove Integer Overflow Checks**".

Comment: i had resorted to a while loop

Comment: but if walking backwards through a for-loop is a legitimate operation, then shouldn't the compiler side step this or treat this as a special case?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try this ..

```
Dim a As Integer = -1
For i As ULong = ULong.MaxValue To 0 Step CULng(a)

Next i
```

Comment: should fail to compile still

Comment: duh :) -1 unsigned? compiles, but fails with overflow<bang_head_against_wall>

Comment: plus one for effort bro :)